# PHP - Pull data from mysql and e-mail

Tags: php

In the code below, I can run the sql through phpMyAdmin and it will return a result. It does not throw any php errors on the browser. I can't seem to get it to send out e-mail.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
include('database.inc.php'); // Our database connectivity file
?>
<?php
$reminder_date = "t1.`reminder_date`";
$email = "t1.`reminder_email`";
$reminder_name = "t1.`reminder_name`";
$reminder_details = "t1.`reminder_desc`";
$server = "reminder@teamcrr.com";

$sql = "SELECT t1.`reminder_id` , t1.`reminder_name` , t1.`reminder_desc` , t1.`reminder_date` , t1.`reminder_email` , lp4.`email` AS `lp_reminder_email`
FROM `reminder_events` AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN `authorize` AS lp4 ON ( t1.`reminder_email` = lp4.`email` )
WHERE reminder_date <= NOW( )
ORDER BY `reminder_date` ASC";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) )
?>
<?php
 $to = "$email";
 $from = "$server";
 $headers = "$from";
 $subject = "$reminder_name";
 $body = "$reminder_details";


 {
 $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
 }

 ?>
```

Anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: remove the @ from the mail function at the bottom and try again. "@" is the error suppression operator and any function prefaced with that will not throw errors regardless of error_reporting status.

Comment: Just to verify, the closing ?> you have on line 3 of your non-working code isn't there in your actual code?

Comment: I did that, and still not getting e-mails sent out. Not throwing any errors, either. Thanks.

Comment: is that first block the entire block that you're running?

Comment: Yes, I edited the code above to show exactly what I have now. But when I pasted it onto the page, it throws off the formatting.

Comment: Thank you Marc B for fixing the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not fetching your query results properly. `mysql_fetch_array()` simply returns a result row as an array, where $row[0] is the first column in the result, $row[1](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) is the 2nd column, etc...

As well, you've construct the fetch loop improperly, so you're never properly retrieving a row. In essence, your email is being send to "t1`.reminder_email". Your $header is also invalid. Your code SHOULD look something like this:

```
<?php
    include('database.inc.php'); // Our database connectivity file
    $server = "reminder@teamcrr.com";

$sql = <<<EOL
SELECT t1.reminder_id AS reminder_id, t1.reminder_name AS reminder_name,
    t1.reminder_desc AS reminder_desc, t1.reminder_date AS reminder_date,
    t1.reminder_email AS reminder_email, lp4.email AS lp_reminder_email
FROM reminder_events AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN authorize AS lp4 ON ( t1.reminder_email = lp4.email )
WHERE reminder_date <= NOW()
ORDER BY reminder_date ASC;
EOL;

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $to = $row['reminder_email'];
    $subject = $row['reminder_name'];
    $body = $row['reminder_desc'];

    mail($to, $subject, $body);
}
```

If you need to mess with the mail headers, then I suggest you use a proper mail package, such as [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) or [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), which can properly set them for you without having to deal with the nitty-gritty details.

In your code, you had:

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) )
?>
<?php
 $to = "$email";
```

Which parses to the following:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   $to = $email;
}
```

Because of the misplaced braces (`{}`), the entire result set was being consumed on a useless loop of `$to = $email`, and never sending the mail until AFTER all the rows had been wasted. That left your $email at the original field name you'd set above, and so you were trying to send mail to a user named "t1.reminder_mail", which no doubt does not exist on your mail server.

Comment: You're welcome. If this all worked properly for you, you can accept this answer.